# discord.py - How do I send a message to multiple channels?

Tags: python, discord.py

So... I wanted to make an code so it send an message to an specific channel

I want so it send this message in chat `#logs` and `#mod-log`

Heres the code:

```
channel = discord.utils.get(user.server.channels, name=['logs', 'mod-log'])
embed = discord.Embed(name="MEMBER_WARNED", description="------------------------------------------------------", color=0xffaa00)
embed.set_author(name="MEMBER_WARNED:\nMember Warned")
embed.add_field(name="Warned by: ", value="{}".format(author.mention), inline=False)
client = bot
await client.send_message(channel, embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to send a separate message to each channel:

```
channels = [channel for channel in user.server.channels if channel.name in ['logs', 'mod-log']]
embed = discord.Embed(name="MEMBER_WARNED", description="------------------------------------------------------", color=0xffaa00)
embed.set_author(name="MEMBER_WARNED:\nMember Warned")
embed.add_field(name="Warned by: ", value="{}".format(author.mention), inline=False)
for channel in channels:
    await bot.send_message(channel, embed=embed)
```